# How video is played in the QML?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qml, qtmultimedia

I am new to qml. I would like to know how the video is played in the qml. How the video is handled in the back-end(The classes and modules responsible for video playback). How can i add a custom player to play back video in QML? Is there any documents on this? Is there any tutorial for writing the qt-plugin for video playback.

I don't know where to start looking? Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LaszloPapp could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are a newcomer to the topic, so I will start with the basics.

The responsible part of the Qt architecture is [QtMultimedia](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmultimedia-index.html) for this. That is the module I would start taking a look at. This essential modul is responsible for the audio and video bits in Qt. It deals with the boiler plate as well as the convenient higher-level interface like QML.

It really depends on what video playback you would like to write. You can find the existing backends in [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Multimedia_Backends).

As for writing a new backend and/or plugin, [this post](http://thebugfreeblog.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/hardware-accelerated-qtmultimedia.html) gives some insight how this has been achieved for one. [The official documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/multimediabackend.html) about is also a recommended material for reading.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay...Let met Check the links